# aspectj - Intertype method declaration not working with Maven

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm having troubles compiling a project with Maven and AspectJ.

This the POM excerpt for `aspectj-maven-plugin` (taken from effective POM):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-aj-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-core</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-persistence</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
                <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspects</testAspectDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-aj-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-core</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-test</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-persistence</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
                <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspects</testAspectDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-aj-generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-persistence</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
                <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspects</testAspectDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-aj-generate-test-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.jcz</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcz-persistence</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
                <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspects</testAspectDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspects</aspectDirectory>
        <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspects</testAspectDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When launching an `mvn clean deploy` I got these lines:

```
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:test-compile (default-aj-generate-test-sources) @ jcz-persistence-jpa ---
[INFO] 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java:45) is annotated with @Entity type annotation from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:79)
[INFO] 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java:45) is annotated with @UUID type annotation from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:80)
[INFO] Extending interface set for type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) to include 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj)
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'boolean org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.equals(java.lang.Object)')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'java.lang.String org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.toSuperString()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'java.lang.String org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.toString()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'org.jcz.persistence.UniqueIdentifier org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.uniqueIdentifier()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'java.util.Comparator<java.lang.reflect.Method> org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.retrieveComparatorForAction(java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>)')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'java.lang.String org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.retrieveDescriptionForAction(java.lang.annotation.Annotation)')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.invokeActions(java.lang.Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation>)')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPrePersist()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPostPersist()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPreUpate()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPostUpdate()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPreRemove()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.EntitySupportAspect' (EntitySupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.persistence.EntitySupport.doPostRemove()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped field from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj:'java.lang.String org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID.id')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj:'java.io.Serializable org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID.getId()')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID.setId(java.io.Serializable)')
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj:'void org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID.ensureId()')
```

Just to reduce the scope to a single case:

```
[INFO] Type 'org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band' (Band.java) has intertyped method from 'org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect' (UUIDSupportAspect.aj:'java.io.Serializable org.jcz.aspects.persistence.UUIDSupportAspect$WithUUID.getId()')
```

So, it looks like the method `getId()` is correctly injected into the class `Band`. But when Maven proceeds to tests compilation and unit testing:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project jcz-persistence-jpa: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

and, amongst other error details, I got

```
[ERROR] /home/stefano/projects/java/jcz-persistence-jpa/src/test/java/org/jcz/persistence/jpa/ServiceTestCase.java:[182,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method getId()
[ERROR] location: variable persisted of type org.jcz.persistence.jpa.model.Band
[ERROR] /home/stefano/projects/java/jcz-persistence-jpa/src/test/java/org/jcz/persistence/jpa/ServiceTestCase.java:[182,60]
```

as if all my intertype declared stuff weren't injected, after all.

To check if there was some error in the code, I tried running the JUnit tests from within Eclipse, and everything worked fine.

So I guess there is something in the maven compilation process that I didn't set up correctly.

Can anyone help me understand what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally came up with a solution. Leaving track here.

What I did to solve the issue was configuring the `maven-compiler-plugin` like that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.${java.version}</source>
        <target>1.${java.version}</target>
        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where the most important part is **`<useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>`**

Comment: This is actually a known but unfixed problem in Maven Compiler Plugin because the switch does the opposite of what it advertised. It actually does use incremental compilation if you set the switch to `false`. Very annoying. I have mentioned that in so many answers here on SO, just haven't been around for a while, but you found out by yourself. :-) BTW, you can accept your own answer in order to close the question.

Comment: thanks a lot @kriegaex! Even if I solved the issue that time, I never inquired the reason why it happened. Now that I know, I also solved a problem I had in compilation within the latest Eclipse relesases (late 2019 onward) :-)

Answer (score 0):

To make inter-type declaration work with aspectj-maven-plugin, one needs to configure maven-compiler-plugin by adding an option failOnError:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The solution is taken from https://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/05/aspectj-inter-type-declaration.html